# wordpress url rewrite to subdomain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying now to move a website to wordpress, my issue that I need to keep the old URLs life as it was, withut any change.

I already have the URLs and each post content inside a DB, and want to rewrite the URL to match the old URLs (it includes sub domains).

What I want to do:
1- Add new field inside the posts table for the old URL
2- Rewrite the wordpress link to match the old URL stored in the DB

example

```
http://example.com/?p=N
```

rewrite to

```
http://sub.example.com/posttitle
```

So when the visitor trying to access any of the old URLs, can get a result.
Is this possible?